# Online version of Sulba Sutras by Baudhayana

Tags: resource, sruti

[Sulba Sutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulba_Sutras) are texts belonging to the [Srauta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Arauta) ritual (based on *Sruti*) containing geometry of *Yagna* related constructions.

Where can I find an online version of the Sulba Sutras by Baudhayana? By original, I mean the Sanskrit Shlokas should be there. Translation is not a requisite.

Comment: Couldnt find anything in the wiki references or the archive site.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want **Shulba Sutras** out of all texts?

Comment: @Surya I am reading a research paper which talks about 'the knowledge of prime numbers numbers in Vedas etc.' It has quite a few references to Sulba Sutras, amongst other texts. Except this, other texts, I am able to find. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can get original Sanskrit text of Baudhayana Shulba Sutra from:

- [Vedic Reserve](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/kalpa/shulba/baudhayana_shulba_sutra.pdf)
- [Sanskrit Wikisource](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D)

Note: If you don't know reading Devanagari, you may use [transliteration tool](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript).